# Why do common diseases tend to be polyfactorial, while rare diseases often involve a single gene?

Tags: genetics

[This answer by xiota](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/a/19334/43) to [Why do gene therapies so often target rare disease?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/19331/14759) states:

> Common diseases tend to be polyfactorial, while rare diseases often involve a single gene. Many involve just a single mutation event (substitution, deletion, addition, inversion, etc).

Why do common diseases tend to be polyfactorial, while rare diseases often involve a single gene? One could think that it is more likely to have one single  mutation than to have a combination of several factors.